# Bedtools genomecov gives me coverage files showing zeros at all nucleotide positions

Tags: rna-seq, bedtools

Also posted [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9587718/)

I have bam files that I've obtained through STAR alignment. Here is the first 10 lines of one of my bam files:

```
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1126:15501:17879 0       chromosome      1       255     11S139M *       0       0       ATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGGTAGTGATTTCCGACTTCACGCTACAACAGG  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:137        nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1126:15130:18427 0       chromosome      1       255     11S139M *       0       0       ATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGGTAGTGATTTCCGACTTCACGCTACAACAGG  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF::FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:137        nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1206:9272:29857  0       chromosome      1       255     28S108M14S      *       0       0       GGCGGTTTGGCGTGCGTATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGAGATCGGAAGAGCG  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:106        nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1266:30734:10692 0       chromosome      1       255     24S126M *       0       0       GTTTGGCGTGCGTATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGGTAGTGATTTCCGACTTC  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFF  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:124        nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1266:31412:33411 0       chromosome      1       255     24S126M *       0       0       GTTTGGCGTGCGTATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGGTAGTGATTTCCGACTTC  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF::FFFFFFF:FFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFF,FFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFF::FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFF:F,FFFFF  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:124        nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1330:21938:10708 0       chromosome      1       255     16S134M *       0       0       TGCGTATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGGTAGTGATTTCCGACTTCACGCTACA  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFF,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:F  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:132        nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1367:17074:4726  0       chromosome      1       255     11S82M  *       0       0       ATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGG   FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  NH:i:1   HI:i:1  AS:i:80 nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1367:11939:11584 0       chromosome      1       255     11S82M  *       0       0       ATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGG   FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFF:F:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  NH:i:1   HI:i:1  AS:i:80 nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1372:24740:30843 0       chromosome      1       255     16S48M  *       0       0       TGCGTATTTCCATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAA        FFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF        NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:47 nM:i:0
GWNJ-1013:671:GW2304233104th:2:1401:11107:19319 0       chromosome      1       255     5S144M1S        *       0       0       ATCACAACTGCTCCTCGGAAGTCGACCAACAAGTCAGCTATGACTTGGCATAATTTGTGCCGACAAAATGCGCGCAGAGTATAGGGGTGGATTAACCCCTATTCAACTCTTCGGTAGTGATTTCCGACTTCACGCTACAACAGGAATTGA  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFF  NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:142        nM:i:0
```

This is the script I'm using that contains the `genomecov -d -pc -ibam` command:

```
BAM_DIR='./sorted_bam_files'

# Loop over each BAM file in the directory
for file in "$BAM_DIR"/*_high_mapq_reads.sorted.bam
do
    echo "Calculating coverage for $file..."
    # Get the basename of the file
    base=$(basename "$file")
    # Calculate coverage
    bedtools genomecov -d -pc -ibam $file > "${base%.sorted.bam}.coverage"
done
```

This is the output I keep getting (first 10 lines only shown). I've tried this with at least 30 other bam files but the output is always the same.

```
chromosome      1       0
chromosome      2       0
chromosome      3       0
chromosome      4       0
chromosome      5       0
chromosome      6       0
chromosome      7       0
chromosome      8       0
chromosome      9       0
chromosome      10      0
```

Any ideas on why this keeps happening? I don't think there's something wrong with my bam files because I was able to use them for DGE analyses and also checked to see if most reads were getting unmapped but they weren't. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is your first chromosome called "chromosome", that's odd.

Comment: @ATpoint also second column `FLAG == 0` and the fifth `MAPQ ==255` meaning: "A value 255 indicates that the mapping quality is not available.". Then the CIGARs looking like the read was indeed mapped `11S82M` etc.

Comment: @ATpoint The data I have is from bacteria, so I'm only working with 1 chromosome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option `-pc` is for

```
-pc     Calculate coverage of pair-end fragments.
```

but your reads are single-end reads

Comment: What tells you they're single ends? Is it because you know this would happen with `-pc` and single end files or was it something in the bam?

Comment: "What tells you they're single ends? Is it b" : the sam flags of each alignemt is zero. Paired would have the '1' bit set . see https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/explain-flags.html

Comment: Using that page, I can see that 11S139M, the first one, is "read paired", "read mapped in proper pair" and "mate unmapped". Could you explain a bit more please? Ideally, adding the detail in the answer so the next user who is confused can also find the info?

Comment: the second column is the read flag (section 1.4 of https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf) . it's always 0  in your example.  0 is single end read mapped on plus strand.

Comment: Ah thanks, yes, I was looking at the cigar string, duh. It would be great if you could add some more detail to the answer to make all this clear. Especially since I don't see mention of 0 meaning "single end" either in the specs (but perhaps I missed it) or when using the explain-flags page (which just ignores 0).

Comment: "I don't see mention of 0 meaning "single end" either in the specs (but perhaps I missed it)" it's a array of bits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array . The first bit is for "Read Paired". As it's not set, the read is not part of a "Read Paired", hence it's single end.

Comment: @Pierre Some of my bam files have a mix of 0 and 16 for my read flags. So to my understanding I have a mix of single-end and paired-end reverse strand reads. Do I include or omit `-pc`?